# Why is integration by parts derived as the following way?

Tags: calculus, integration

### Deriving the integration by parts formula:

$$\frac{d}{dx}[f(x)g(x)] = f'(x)g(x)+f(x)g'(x)$$

$$f(x)g(x) =\int{f'(x)g(x)}\:dx + \int{f(x)g'(x)}\:dx$$

$$=>\int{f(x)g'(x)}\:dx =f(x)g(x) - \int{g(x)f'(x)}\:dx$$

$$ OR $$
$$\frac{d}{dx}[uv] = vdu+udv$$

$$uv =\int{v}\:du + \int{u}\:dv$$

$$=>\int{u}\:dv = uv - \int{v}\:du$$

---

### **My question:**

In this step of deriving the integration by parts formula,
$$uv =\int{v}\:du + \int{u}\:dv$$

$$=>\int{u}\:dv = uv - \int{v}\:du$$

Why is $\int{v}\:du$ subtracted from $uv$? In other words, I can subtract either integral from $uv$ in order to isolate either integral. So why can't I do the following? :
$$uv =\int{v}\:du + \int{u}\:dv$$

$$=>\int{v}\:du = uv - \int{u}\:dv$$

When I then use this formula shown above, integrating something by parts will no longer work. See the **example** below:

$$\int{x}{sinx}\:dx$$

### $Correct$ $integral$$: -xcosx + sinx + C$

---

### Case 1

$$\int{x}{sinx}\:dx$$

Using:

$$\int{v}\:du = uv - \int{u}\:dv$$

$$u = x -> du = dx$$
$$dv = sinxdx -> v = -cosx$$

$$= -xcosx + \int{xsinx}\:dx$$

As you can see the integral on the right side is the same as the original, so it will keep repeating and never give the correct answer of -xcos(x) + sin(x) + C

---

### Case 2

$$\int{x}{sinx}\:dx$$

Using:

$$\int{v}\:du = uv - \int{u}\:dv$$
$$u = sinx -> du = cosxdx$$
$$dv = xdx -> v = 1/2(x^2)$$

Will lead no where close to the correct answer if computed ^

### So why doesn't arranging the form of the integration by parts formula make it no longer work?

If I used the original formula: uv - $\int{v}\:du$, then the integral in my **example** will lead to the correct answer. But if I use uv - $\int{u}\:dv$, then the formula no longer works, as shown above.

---

### Finally resolved:

$\int{u}\:dv = uv - \int{v}\:du$ $<=>$ $\int{v}\:du = uv - \int{u}\:dv$

but the final answer has to be adjusted slightly when using the altered formula in order to get the correct answer. The final answer has to be arranged because both formulas will always have the same $u$ and $v$ values such that one expression/integrand will represent the **original integral** given.

**Normal formula:** 
$\int{u}\:dv = uv - \int{v}\:du$

Original integral: $$\int{x}{sinx}\:dx$$

$$u = x -> du = dx$$
$$dv = sindx -> v = -cosx$$

$$\int{x}{sinx}\:dx= -xcosx + \int{cosx}\:dx$$

### $$= -xcosx + sinx + C $$

**Altered formula:** 
$\int{v}\:du = uv - \int{u}\:dv$

Original integral: $$\int{x}{sinx}\:dx$$

$$u = x -> du = dx$$
$$dv = sindx -> v = -cosx$$

$$\int{-cosx}\:dx = -xcosx - \int{xsinx}\:dx$$
$$\int{x}{sinx}\:dx= -xcosx + \int{cosx}\:dx$$

### $$= -xcosx + sinx + C $$

Comment: It doesn't matter which you subtract: After all, just renaming $u \leftrightarrow v$ replaces one formula with the other.

Comment: I don't know if I did something wrong or confused by something, but in my example it does not work when you arrange the formula

Comment: My first assumption was that subtracting either integral from uv will still work, but I'm not sure if the example I put can still lead to the correct answer.

Comment: If you're convinced that it works one way, then just replace all of the $u$'s in your computations with $v$ and vice versa; that shows that it works the other way.

Comment: Do some examples that don't involve trig. functions first to see that it does work.  Trig functions can be tricky as you sometimes need to invoke their periodicity to see that two expressions are equivalent.

Comment: In my example, no matter what I choose u to be, the result will not be correct.

Comment: @Jtheconstant Again, write out your work for the order that you're convinced works, then literally erase and replace every $u$ with $v$ and vice versa. That will in particular give you a choice of $u$ and $v$ for which the "other" integration by parts rule holds.

Comment: I am doing it right now, but if I swap the integrals in the formula as shown in my question will it still work? Right now it seems like it doesn't even though it makes sense for it to also work

Comment: Yes I agree that swapping the integrals in the integration by parts formula should still give the correct answer, but for some reason in my example, using the altered formula does not lead to the correct answer. I'm not sure if I did something wrong or if the formula doesn't work

Comment: Again, the identity still holds, exactly because changing the names of the variables does not change whether the identity is valid. Therefore, there is something wrong in your computation or reasoning. When you carried out the exercise you said you were doing, compare the steps with the methods in your problem statement; that will show you where any computational error is.

Comment: I have done the steps on paper, and it is exactly the same as I have shown in my question. For the first case in the example, you can see that I would have to apply integration by parts twice, since the integrand after doing integration by parts for the first time still contains two different expressions. Regardless of this, is there something I did wrong in my calculations? I've looked at both cases of the example and they seem computionally correct but the final answer of both cases still doesn't match the original answer of -xcos(x) + sin(x) +C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making a mistake in both of your other cases of determining the integral of different expressions. You have the original integral of

$$\int x\sin(x)dx = -x\cos x + \sin x + C \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

However, with $u = x$, you get $du = dx$. With $v = \sin x$, you have

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\int vdu & = \int \sin(x)dx \\
& = x\sin x - \int x\cos x dx \\
& = -\cos x + C
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Also, with $u = \sin(x)$, you get $du = \cos(x)dx$. Along with $v = x$, you have

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\int vdu & = \int x\cos(x)dx \\
& = x\sin x - \int \sin x dx \\
& = x\sin x + \cos x + C
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

As you can see, the integrals used in both \eqref{eq2A} or \eqref{eq3A} don't match that in \eqref{eq1A}. Thus, there's no reason to expect the resulting expressions to match either, and they don't as you can see.

Comment: ? The formula I'm testing is  uv - integral of udv. In either case of my example of choosing different expressions for u, the answer will not be correct as shown in my example

Comment: there is no du in my formula, I used the terms u, v, dv

Comment: @Jtheconstant You don't show all of the details of your first example, but consider your second one. Your original integral is $\int x\sin x dx = -x\cos x + \sin x + C$. However, in the second case, like I showed in my ($3$), the LHS is $\int x \cos x dx$, you get that $\int x \cos x dx = x\sin x + \cos x + C$. This is different from your original integral result, but note you are determining a *different* integral. The result is correct for the second integral. As for your statement "there is no du in my formula", well your LHS is $\int vdu$, so you are using $du$.

Comment: For u = x, v=sinx, dv= cosxdx, I differentiated v, didn't integrate it because the formula I used was uv - the integral of udv. So dv must contain the dx term, hence dv is the derivative of v not the integral of v.

Comment: If there is no reason to expect the resulting expressions to match, then the slightly altered integration by parts formula I used is invalid? Because I think the formula should still work since I just swapped variables/integrals

Comment: @Jtheconstant The slightly altered version you're using is valid, it's just that it is determining the integrals of different expressions, as I show.

Comment: No I mean as in the altered version of the formula should give the same answer as the original formula which is -xcos(x) + sin(x) + C, since the original question was xsin(x). But in both your answers, neither matches -xcos(x) + sin(x) + C.

Comment: @Jtheconstant Yes, the original question was the integral of $x\sin x$, but the problem is that you're actually calculating different integrals in your $2$ other cases. Unfortunately, you don't seem to be seeing this, and I'm not sure what else I can write to help you. Thus, I suggest to consider again what I wrote, what transecolocation wrote in their answer & comments, plus what other people wrote in various question comments.  Then, please look carefully again at what you did to see if you can then determine what is going wrong. Good luck with figuring this out.

Comment: I think I almost figured this out. I will update my question when I figure it out

Comment: Oh found out what I did wrong. Seems like the integration by part variables was arranged in the wrong way, which caused things that got differentiated but were supposed to be integrated.

Comment: @Jtheconstant I'm glad you figured out what was going wrong for you. Thanks for letting me know what the issue was.

Comment: Unfortunately I just realized that it's wrong again...

Comment: @Jtheconstant I believe I have an idea of the issue. Note the $u$ and $v$ are *not* fixed. Instead, they need to match what you're trying to solve. In particular, with $\int vdu = uv - \int udv$, you *must* choose a $v$ and $du$ so $vdu$ matches what you're trying to integrate on the LHS. In your case, for $\int x\sin x dx$, you can choose $v = x$, do $dv = dx$, and $du = \sin x dx$, so $u = -\cos x$. Plugging these values in gives $\int vdu = \int x\sin x dx = uv - \int u dv = -x\cos x - \int (-\cos x)dx = -x\cos x + \sin x + C$, as expected. However, $u = x$, $v = \sin x$ gives my ($2$).

Comment: @Jtheconstant With your "First case fixed:" section, you have the LHS being $\int vdu = \int (-\cos x)dx = -\sin x + C$. This means, with your RHS, you now have $-\sin x + C = -x\cos x - \int x\sin x dx \implies \int x\sin x dx = -x\cos x + \sin x + C$, as you stated was correct. Note you made a mistake with the sign as it should be $- \int x\sin x dx$ instead of $+ \int x\sin x dx$.

Comment: Shouldn't the LHS be -xcos(x) not just  -cos(x), since u = x and v = -cosx

Comment: I see what you did, which makes sense. But why does it become tedious where you have to equate the LHS and the RHS when you swap the integrals in the by parts formula? Why can't I just apply the regular steps as the original formula with the altered formula of uv - the integral of udv

Comment: if I used the original formula, I would just find variables of u and v and solve the integral as usual and get the correct answer. but with the altered formula, why can't I do the same steps, in other words why does a new method where LHS must be shown to be equal to RHS when using this altered formula?

Comment: @Jtheconstant I'm not completely clear on what you're asking. There're $2$ variables of $u$ & $v$ to choose. Regardless of choices, you *have* to consistently use them, along with the corresponding $du$ and $dv$, in the formula of either $\int vdu = uv - \int udv$ or $\int udv = uv - \int vdu$. In both cases, you have an equality, so the LHS *must* be equal to the RHS. As for the altered formula, doing the same steps gives the same values for $u$, $du$, $v$ and $dv$, but the LHS integral is different, as I've explained. It's past $2$ a.m. my time, so I'm going to bed. Good luck with this.

Comment: I am really close to the answer now, I think I might have figured out almost

Comment: Finally resolved this problem. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Let's play it through with your first "incorrect" example.

Actually it is correct, but it does not help you to solve the integral you would like to find.

- $u=x, v = \sin x$
- $\Rightarrow \int u\;dv = \int x\;d(\sin x)= \int x\cos x\; dx = x\sin x + \cos x (+ c)$

Hence, ignoring the constant of integration, you get

$$x\sin x = uv = \int u\;dv + \int v\; du = x\sin x + \cos x - \cos x = x\sin x $$
So, **it is correct** but does not solve your problem.
Similarly, for your second "incorrect" case.

Getting back to the original integral:

$$\int \underbrace{x}_{u} \underbrace{\sin x\;dx}_{dv}$$

So, setting $\boxed{u=x}$ you have $\boxed{dv=\sin x dx} \Rightarrow \boxed{v= -\cos x}$. Hence, simply setting $v=\sin x$ instead and expecting to get a correct result for the integral does not work.

Comment: For your answer: xsinx+cosx(+c), I think it is incorrect because it seems like the integration by parts formula you used is wrong. It seems like you used the product rule in the integration by parts formula. Shouldn't it be uv - the integral of vdu?

Comment: You can verify the correctness of an antiderivative by differentiation. You have $(x\sin x + \cos x)' = x\cos x$.

Comment: @Jtheconstant : Have you checked the last part of my answer? There you can see that setting $v=\sin x$ while $u=x$ leads to something different than the integral you would like to calculate.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but your question is immaterial.

You are asking why

$$\int u\,dv=uv-\int v\,du$$

rather than

$$\int v\,du=uv-\int u\,dv.$$

Notice that these are completely equivalent by swapping the roles of $u$ and $v$.

---

Taking your example, we set

$$u=x,\\dv=\sin x\,dx=-d\cos x$$ and

$$\int x\sin x\,dx=-x\cos x+\int\cos x\,dx=-x\cos x+\sin x+c.$$

---

Your confusion comes from the fact that there are two ways to apply the by-parts method, integrating one of the factors or the other. After integration, you differentiate the other factor. Depending on the cases, this can lead to a simplification or not.

For a product like $x\sin x$, it is possible to integrate both factors, but $x\to\dfrac{x^2}2$ brings no simplification, whereas integrating $\sin x$ will result in $x\to1$.

Integration by parts is not a symmetrical process. It is a matter of experience to choose the right factor.

---

**A last word:**

Sometimes its pays to consider a virtual factor $1$ and integrate on it,

$$\int f(x)\,dx=\int 1\cdot f(x)\,dx=x\,f(x)-\int x\,f'(x)\,dx.$$

Comment: I know that both are equivalent, but when I do an example as shown in my question using this altered formula, the answer is wrong as shown

Comment: "altered" as in: uv - the integral of udv, instead of the original formula: uv - the integral of vdu.

Comment: And your solution to the integral is correct, but that is using the original formula. When I use the altered formula, it gives the wrong answer

Comment: @Jtheconstant: see my update.

Comment: So if integration by parts is not a symmetrical process, the altered formula will give a different answer from the original formula?

Comment: and also I made this question because I want to know more about how the by parts formula is derived. I don't like just memorizing formulas